# Warning messages glmer

Tags: r

I am trying to fit the following glmer: litter decomposition (proportion) as a function of the covariates. Fixed covariates are tea type (categorical with two levels), microhabitat (categorical with three levels), MAP (continuous) and MAT (continuous). The interaction terms are MAT x MAP, MAT x microhabitat and MAP x microhabitat. We use plot nested to site as random effect to account the dependence of observations within plots within sites.

MAP1<-MAP/100

```
M2<-glmer(Fraction_decomposed~MAT*MAP1*Treatment+Tea+(1|Site/Plot),family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

But I obtained the following warning messages:

```
Warning messages:
1: In eval(family$initialize, rho) :
  non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
3: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50OzY.png)

I also tried transforming the response variable and performed a lmer, but I read that transformations are not recommended

Fraction_decomposed1<-logit(Fraction_decomposed)

M3<-lmer(Fraction_decomposed1~MAT*MAP1*Treatment+Tea+(1|Site/Plot))
isSingular(M3)
Anova(M3)
summary(M3)

Comment: Please post a __minimal reproducible example__. Is your outcome 0/1 or a factor with 2 levels?

Comment: For logit, you need to provide either a binary (0 or 1, or factor) or a matrix of success /  failure, for example if you have 0.4, originating from 4 success and 6 failure, you will have it as c(4,6)

Comment: If you provide an example of your data, and also this success / failure information, can show u the code

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. The response variable is a proportion (0-1). I have five different forests, in each forest three plots, in each plot three treatments and each treatment, in each treatment two different teas.